# Using GPO to install/update java on windows terminal servers

Tags: group-policy, terminal-server

We've been using GPO to manage java + reader installs on user PCs for a while now... I'm wondering if there would be any issue using the same method on terminal servers. 
How do you handle switching to install mode?   Or is it not required since it installs at startup?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "java + reader"? Do you mean Adobe Reader?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an **MSI-based** solution that installs for **all users**, you shouldn't need to change anything for the process to work on a terminal server. There's other considerations for managing programs that exist on a terminal server, but the installation itself doesn't care what the system setup is like.